# using Unix functions in OCaml source

Tags: unix, ocaml

I have a function to get the current time using the unix *gettimeofday()* in function *time.ml*.  The file accesses the function in the following way:

```
open Unix; (*declared at the top of the file*)

let get_time ()  = Unix.gettimeofday ()
```

The corresponding entry in *.mli* file is like this:

```
val get_time : unit -> float
```

But during compiling them throws an error:

```
File "_none_", line 1, characters 0-1:
No implementations provided for the following modules:
Unix referenced from time.cmx
```

I have checked that the following files are present in */lib/ocaml* directory:

```
unix.cmi, unix.a unix.cma unix.cmx unix.cmxa unix.cmxs unix.mli
```

and the path is set correctly set to  in *.bashrc* file.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib
```

Other functions like *fprintf* from *Printf* module work correctly inspite of being in the same */lib/ocaml* directory.

Any ideas what could be wrong? Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: > Any ideas what could be wrong? Am I doing something wrong or am I
> missing something? You didn't read the documentation attentively. E.g. [OCaml manual : The unix library](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-312/manual035.html)
or [ocaml-tutorial : Compiling OCaml projects](http://mirror.ocamlcore.org/ocaml-tutorial.org/compiling_ocaml_projects.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to compile like this:

```
ocamlc unix.cma -c time.mli time.ml (* bytecode *)
```

or

```
ocamlopt unix.cmxa -c time.mli time.ml  (* native code *)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a properly configured findlib,

`ocamlfind ocamlopt -package Unix -linkpkg time.ml`

will save you the trouble of picking the .cma or the .cmxa version.